# Event Click On MovieClips Mask (Non Transparent Area)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, movieclip

I'm working with Flash CS6 to create MovieClips that I want to use in my AS3 project using Linked Classes, I'm trying to detect when the mouse is clicking the MovieClip, but the event is fired also when I click the transparent area of the PNG image used to create the MovieClip, and I want to fire the event only when I click the non transparent area of the Movieclip (the mask), is there any work around I can do in Flash CS5 or with AS3 code !

Answer (score 1):

You should add an instance name to the mask (which means it must be a symbol), and then add listener directly on the mask, not on the whole movie clip.

Another solution is to set `mouseEnabled` and `mouseChildren` to `false` on that bitmap, and leave only the area you wish to be clickable.

Comment: .. Hi, how do i get the mask from the MovieClip so i can a listener to it and i didn't understand the second solution, thank you.

Comment: Bitmaps can actually not receive mouse events so "another solution" is out the question.

Comment: What I meant is if he placed bitmap inside a `MovieClip`, then added `MouseEvent` listener to the **MovieClip**, then he gets clicks on the `Bitmap`. Disabling the bitmap anyhow will fix this (either mouseEnabled, or mouseChildren to the MC).

Comment: .. @Andrey Hi again, sorry for the late response, i was wondering if you have any examples about what you said !

Comment: It's best that you provide any code/samples of what's your problem. We're not magicians here :)